# Image Writer not working - missing partition table

Tags: live-usb, disk-image

I have downloaded the Windows 10 iso file and first, I tried to write it to my 16GB USB with the command `sudo dd if=Win10.iso of=/dev/sdb` and it didn't work so I tried balena etcher. it says missing partition table. Can you help me with this please? the iso file works perfect on a VM BTW[image]

Comment: You probably destroyed the partition table by doing `dd` first. Try partitioning your USB drive again and then use Etcher. Just make sure you're picking the right drive.

Comment: Just read the error message more closely, and it seems to complain about the iso and not the drive indeed. Where is that iso from anyway? And what's with the libreoffice tag?

Comment: use gparted to format flash disk

Comment: This answer may help you. https://askubuntu.com/a/12293/124466

Comment: Use mkusb-dus or mkusb-plug to make your installer USB. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Hi. Thank you. I haven't heard of mkusb. Is it really a safe tool?

Comment: @Python is cool: mkusb-plug goes to great lengths to be safe. It double checks everything. Much, much safer than dd, (AKA disk destroyer).

Comment: @C.S.Cameronbt safe I meant malware. I don't want it to ad malware to the USB because it is not on the ubuntu repository

Comment: @Python is cool: Sudodus, the maintainer, has been answering questions on Ask Ubuntu for close to nine years and has a very high reputation here, (34,266). He is Staff Emeritus over at Ubuntu Forums and has also been helping people there for over nine years. He will provide Source Code if you ask.

Comment: @Python My understanding is that mkusb just does what dd does, it just does it safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution for Windows 10.
Please assume that `/dev/sdx` is the block device of the USB stick.

Note: there are little differences between `< v1809` and `>= v1809` that are noticed in screendump.

Open a terminal session, then:

```
sudo su
DEVICE=/dev/sdx

# wipe MBR
dd if=/dev/zero of=$DEVICE bs=1M count=1

# new partition table
fdisk ${DEVICE}
n
p
1
ENTER
ENTER
t
c
a
w

# new filesystem
mkfs.vfat ${DEVICE}1

# mount it
mkdir /mnt/usb
mount ${DEVICE}1 /mnt/usb

# win 10 as loop device
mkdir /mnt/Win10
mount -o loop /path/to/Win10_x64.iso /mnt/Win10

# copy files from iso to usb-stick:

# if win 10 version < 1809
  cp -a /mnt/Win10/* /mnt/usb

# if version >= 1809
  apt install wimtools
  rsync -avP --exclude='sources/install.wim' /mnt/Win10/ /mnt/usb/
  wimsplit /mnt/Win10/sources/install.wim /mnt/usb/sources/install.swm 2500

# clean up
umount /mnt/usb
umount /mnt/Win10
rm /mnt/usb
rm /mnt/Win10
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized it is not a good idea to make a windows 10 installation USB with Linux distros. The best way is to have it done by a windows c or installing Windows on a virtual machine and making the USB there if your main OS is Linux.